# marionette.js vs Backbone updating DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, marionette

I have noticed there is a different, the way DOM been updated by Marionette comparing with Backbone. I have created two simple fiddles. One using Backbone and other one based on marionette. Both examples has a helper method call processDom and that method simply throw an error after iterating 50 times.

However in backbone example elements been appended to DOM till die() method fires. But in marionette based example DOM has not been updated at all. It would be great if someone can explain how this works. I wonder marionette internally using a virtual dom kind of a technique.

Render method in marionette example

```
render: function () {
            var viewHtml = this.template({
                'contentPlacement': 'Sydney'
            });
            this.$el.html(viewHtml);
            this.processDom(this.$el);
            this.postRender();
        }
```

Render method in backbone example

```
render: function () {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#sample-template').html());
        var viewHtml = template({
                'contentPlacement': 'Sydney'
            });
        this.$el.html(viewHtml);
        this.processDom(this.$el);
        this.postRender();
    },
```

Links to fiddle examples

http://jsfiddle.net/samitha/v5L7c2t5/7/

http://jsfiddle.net/samitha/pc2cvmLs/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In general** for post processing purposes you could use `onRender` of `Marionette.ItemView`. It's not a good practice to rewrite `Marionette.ItemView.render`.

Rendering of views inside the regions for `Marionette` is handled a bit different as in `Backbone` case.

When you rendering `Backbone.View` - your element will attach itself to the DOM's `$('#search-container')`, and in `render` method it will operate with already attached element so you can see the changes.

When you rendering `Marionette.ItemView` with `Marionette.Region.show` method, `Marionette.Region` already attached to the DOM and it need to render appropriate view (in your case `ItemView`) and only after that step it will attach it to the DOM and will set the `ItemView` as `currentView`.

You can see from [source](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette#section-155) of `Marionette.Region.show` that it attaches view after `render` is called. In your case `render` will throw error and it will never be attached to the DOM.

---

To understand it deeper lets look at the 2 methods which are responsible for attaching/creating views in BackboneView. Marionette uses the same method for `Marionette.ItemView`.

```
_ensureElement: function() {
  if (!this.el) { // case when el property not specified in view
    var attrs = _.extend({}, _.result(this, 'attributes'));
    if (this.id) attrs.id = _.result(this, 'id');
    if (this.className) attrs['class'] = _.result(this, 'className');
    // creating new jQuery element(tagNam is div by default) with attributes specified
    var $el = Backbone.$('<' + _.result(this, 'tagName') + '>').attr(attrs);
    this.setElement($el, false);
  } else {  // case when el property exists
    this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el'), false);
  }
}
```

And

```
setElement: function(element, delegate) {
  if (this.$el) this.undelegateEvents();
  // here is all magic
  // if element is instance of Backbone.$, which means that el property not specified
  //  or it's already jquery element like in your example( el: $('#search_container')) with Backbone. 
  // this.$el will be just a jQuery element or already attached to the DOM jQuery element
  // in other case it will try to attach it to the DOM.
  this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
  this.el = this.$el[0];
  if (delegate !== false) this.delegateEvents();
  return this;
},
```

As you can see from comments all magic is in a few lines of code, and that's why I love it.

Comment: Great answer @vahan-vardanyan. Does this mean if I properly use Marionette I don't need to use **documentFragment** to overcome one of the common issues in backbone apps which is heavy DOM modification? Heavy DOM modification becomes an issue when there are so many nested views. This issue also been discussed in [link](http://ozkatz.github.io/avoiding-common-backbonejs-pitfalls.html) In section **Causing multiple DOM reflows when rendering collections**

Comment: Great article. Yes! For collection rendering Marionette will use that technic. You can checkout the source and will see documentFragment there.